# php strip_tags not removing div (and others)

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm trying to validate a comment form using AJAX/PHP, very nearly done now except the strip_tags function in php doesn't seem to remove all elements. Here's what I have:

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$msg = strip_tags( $msg );
```

This function only seems to be removing the closing tags. E.g. `<div>` entered into the message box is not being removed where `</div>` *is* being removed.
I want to literally remove every html element in the message. How do I achieve this?

Thanks, Dan.

Edit:

I feel like a complete idiot!

I have a validate function separate from my show comment function and just realised my mistake. I was never running strip_tags on the message I was displaying!

Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Comment for those who may have found themselves in my situation. If you're stripping HTML tags that are generated by a templating language (for example, Wordpress shortcodes), be sure that the templates have rendered first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one thing that `strip_tags()` can fail with is `htmlentities()`.

it will make `<div>` appear as `%3Cdiv%3E` for example.

Try this. htmlentities will convert code eg. `%3C` to HTML, eg. `<`

```
$msg = strip_tags(htmlentities($msg));
```

you should be able to see what you're trying to debug by comparing these:

```
echo $msg . '<br/>';
echo strip_tags($msg) . '<br/>';
echo htmlentities($msg) . '<br/>';
echo strip_tags(htmlentities($msg)) . '<br/>';
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. htmlentities won't convert entities to HTML but the other way around eg. HTML to entities. I believe the function you're intending to use was html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0):

> [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)() sees a tag as a case-insensitive string between < and the
>   first whitespace or >

Thus `strip_tags('< / div >')` or `strip_tags('< div >')` would give no change if you have any whitespace in there.

You may wish to post an example of the string you're trying to clean.

You should also try echoing $msg directly and viewing the emitted source. Since you're POSTing the data (depending on how you're sending the data from the client) you may find you're actually trying to strip `%3Cdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E` (which is valid) instead of the `<div></div>` you'd expect.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said (without spaces) because I couldn't figure out how to include it in my question as a whole word :S sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Revised with alternative explanation as a result of your clarification.